# License Display Name Change

Tags: licenses, ui, name

I am looking for a way if we can change the display name of licenses which are shown under Company information in UI. Please let me know if this is possible, Thanks.

Comment: I do not think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

From the Company Information Page, you can only [View Your Organization’s User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_view.htm&type=5) but cannot modify them. If you attempt to modify the userLicense display name from API, you will see the error shown in the screenshot below. This is expected

To make any changes to the UserLicense it is recommended to do so by making changes to the Profile because every Profile is tied to a license, updating the profile associated with a User will also update the license. However, you cannot update the display name.

[image]